# How Not to Simplify Exponential of Log?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I have the expression

```
Power[x,I y]
```

Both $x,y$ are real. Now I want to write this expression in term of Exponential of Logarithm. The expression can be rewritten as
$$
x^{iy} = e^{i y \log(x)}
$$
Now to do this in mathematica I wrote

```
Log[Power[x, I y]] //. Log[Power[A_, B_]] -> B Log[A]
Exp[%]
```

But this return $x^{i y}$ since Mathematica automatically simplifies this.
How can I stop this behaviour but still be able to have things like

```
Exp[I p] Exp[i y Log[x] //Simplify
```

With the output Exp[i (p + y Log[x])]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your answer to the question: why do you need such a representation? There are several possible answers:

1. It is a part of the final result and you do it to show it in a desired form in some text or presentation.
2. It is an intermediate result. You need it to better see the expression and to decide, how to operate further.

In the case of the answer 1 `HoldForm` function helps:

```
  x^(I*y) /. x -> Exp[HoldForm[Log[x]]] // PowerExpand
```

with the folllowing effect:

[image]

If answer 2 is right, I recommend to put `Hold` instead of `HoldForm` since then you do not forget that there is an expression on hold.

Another simple way is

```
x^(I*y) /. x -> Exp[ln[x]] // PowerExpand

   (* E^(I y ln[x]) *)
```

Mma understands ln[x] as a new still undefined function. You may make all necessary operations with it but as soon as you need to account for its logarithmic nature, make a replacement:

`ln[x]->Log[x]`.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was easy to solve. It is enough to use `HoldForm`

```
Log[Power[x, I y]] //. Log[Power[A_, B_]] -> B Log[A];
Evaluate@%// HoldForm;
Exp@% + Exp[I p] //Simplify
(*E^(I*p + HoldForm[I*y*Log[x]])*)
```